# Mocking a Superclass in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

How can you unit test a class that has a superclass in Spock that invokes method calls form its superclass? Or how do you mock a superclass in Spock?

Ex:

```
class Bar {

  def method1(parm1){
      //Method actions
  }
}


class Foo extends Bar {

   def method2(param1, param2) {          
       //Method actions
       super.method1(param1)
   }
}
```

How can I mock behavior of class `Bar`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use your class `Foo` as a [`Spy`](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#spies). The spy will create an instance of your class `Foo` but gives you the possibility of mocking any public methods declared in your spies class hierarchy.

```
def fooInstance = Spy(Foo)
fooInstance.method1(_) >> 'return value'
```

Comment: This shows how to mock in the subclass, but the original question was about mocking methods in the superclass.  The methods might even have the same name in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spock to test Kotlin classes, you need to make the superclass methods `open` so that Spock can stub them.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you to specify what methods are called actually.

```
setup:
def fooInstance = Spy(Foo)

when: "this try-catch block is debug code"
try {
  // do something with Foo or Bar
}
catch (Exception e) {
}

then:
0 * fooInstance._
```

This site may be useful. -> [Spock Mock Cheatsheet](http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/04/08/spock-mock-cheatsheet/)