# Mocking super#method() in Spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

Dislaimer: there was a question that might look similar, but it's actually different: [Mocking a Superclass in Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481973/mocking-a-superclass-in-spock)

Ex:

```
class Bar {
  def method(){
      return 'bar'
  }
}


class Foo extends Bar {
   def method() {    
       super.method() + ' foo'
   }
}
```

I want to test `Foo` in isolation, i.e. I want to mock `Bar`, like:

```
def "test"() {
    given:
    def foo = GroovySpy(Foo)

    when:
    def result = foo.method()

    then:
    1 * ((Bar) directive).generate() >> 'mockBar'
    result == 'mockBar foo'
}
```

This obviously won't work, but gives the idea what I'm trying to achieve. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out how to do this.

I put there the following:

```
then:
1 * foo.method()
0 * foo._
```

It gave me exact method that has been called after what I call from `when:`, and I put it like this:

```
then:
1 * foo.super$3$method()
```

I'm not sure from where `$3$` is coming from, maybe that's the inheritance level or something, I think if you try this out you might have different numbers.

Comment: Unexpected solution :) Is it stable on different compilers?

Comment: Good question, I think it might be not. But as long as you pin everything including compiler version it should be reproducible. Once something changed that way you can find the new format. This is definitely undocumented feature, using it comes with it's consequences.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea if you want to mock only `Bar.method()`:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
   def superMethod() {
       super.method()
   }

   def method() {    
       superMethod() + ' foo'
   }
}
```

Your test:

```
def "test"() {
    given:
    def foo = new Foo() {
        @Override
        def superMethod() {
            'mockBar'
        }
    }

    expect:
    foo.method() == 'mockBar foo'
}
```

Comment: That's not cute but will work, thanks. Though I found better approach below.